# XEN VPS Speed Limited

Tags: networking, vps, xen, solusvm

I am just wondering if people can help me troubleshoot something. I currently have a dedicated server with Xen SolusVM set up on it. The VPS seems to be limited on its download speed.

I ran a test file (http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/512MB.zip) on the dedicated server and it was downloading at about 20MB/s. I then did the same test on the VPS (logged in as root both times using wget) and it only downloaded at about 500KBps.

Can anyone offer any hints or tips as to where to look if it is limited somehow? In SolusVM it is set as unlimited network speed.

Comment: N/W throughput may vary due to various reason. However best throughput you will get on VM, if machines with better physical CPUs are expected to achieve higher network throughputs. VCPU may be the bottleneck for this network throughput.

Comment: It's the only VPS on the dedicated server at the moment and has all the CPU cores available (E3 1240V2) so I can't understand why it's reducing from 20/30Mb/s to 500KBps.

Comment: can you check your nic configuration? Check the NIC speed too.

Comment: Just have this in the eth0 config on the VPS: DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=72.46.159.53
NETMASK=255.255.255.248

Comment: how about running this "dmesg | grep -i duplex". Run the same commmand on both physical and vm too

Comment: Nothing on the VM. Main is this: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
e1000e: peth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10260/discussion-between-pratapsingh-and-tenatious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had installed something that was throttling the network connection! A fresh install of CentOs and then CloudLinux fixed the issue :)

Comment: What was it that was causing it, specifically?